# Calling javascript from objective-c in cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm using the cordova 4.2.1 framework in iOS objective-c app. At a random moment I would like to call from objective-c a javascript function which resides in www folder.

I have tried as a starting point to call from javascript side a native function, i.e.

```
cordova.exec("function(){}", null, 'MyPlugin', "MyCommand", []);
```

Then in myCommand in objective-c I had

```
[self.commandDelegate evalJs:@"alert(1);"];
```

and it was working fine.

However what I would like is from AppDelegate.m, to call MyCommand and trigger a javascript function.

I have tried to use a sharedInstance of the myPlugin and call MyCommand without any success.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, NEVER edit the AppDelegate.m on a Cordova app, there is always a good alternative to not doing it, if you tell more about your use case maybe I can propose you alternatives.

To execute javascript in any moment, you can make the webview execute it like this

```
NSString * javascriptString = @"alert('test');";
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];
```

In your case, from AppDelegate.m you can do it like this:

```
[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];
```

But again, NEVER do this.

Comment: I'm interested in sending the apns token id to the javascript side. I have found a workaround to have a kind of a poling mechanism from javascript and check whether the user has cancelled or accepted the remote notifications.